# select according to ranking formula

Tags: mysql, ranking

I have a table populated with user-submitted links which have been voted on by other users. The table has a column `votes` as well as a column `date` in the format `2013-05-12 11:52:55`. I now want to select the highest ranking links/rows by using the following formula: (taken from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions))

```
(p - 1) / (t + 2)^1.5
p = votes (points) from users
t = time since submission in hours
```

Obviously selecting by votes alone would be easy (with `select by votes desc`), but how do I implement the above formula in mysql?

TIA!

Answer (score -1):

```
ORDER BY (votes - 1) / POW(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), date))/3600 + 2), 1.5)
```